# powershell foreach name execute invoke-command

Tags: powershell, foreach, invoke-command

I have the folowing code that outpusts names:

```
foreach ($comp in $maschines.name) { $comp }
```

but the folowing does not work, why?

```
foreach ($comp in $maschines.name) { invoke-command -computer comp1 -ScriptBlock { get-vm –VMName $comp | Select-Object VMId | Get-VHD | ft path } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
 foreach ($comp in $maschines.name) { invoke-command -computer comp1 -ScriptBlock { get-vm –VMName $using:comp | Select-Object VMId | Get-VHD | ft path } }
```

added the `using:` to your scriptblock to make use of that local variable you want to use on that other computer.

Comment: could I use  directly somehow:  ` invoke-command -computer comp1 -ScriptBlock { get-vm –VMName $using:maschines.name | Select-Object VMId | Get-VHD | ft path } `

Comment: I get one table for each $comp, can I somehow get all in one table?